# Efficient storage of binary image data

Tags: java, image, binary

I want to store a large number of equally sized large 3D binary images in Java.  My current thought process is to store the information in each bit of a byte[].  Therefore, in the space of one image I could effectively store 8 images (one image per bit).  I have the following loops to get/set the image data.

Set

```
final byte[] storedArray = organData.get(imageNumber);
final short[] binaryArray = getArray(binaryOrgan);

int i=0;
for (short binaryData : binaryArray) {
    byte storedData = (byte)storedArray[i];
    if (binaryData == 0)
        storedData &= ~(1 << bitNumber);
    else
        storedData |= (1 << bitNumber);
    storedArray[i] = storedData;
    ++i;
}
```

Get

```
final byte[] storedArray = organData.get(imageNumber);
final short[] binaryArray = getArray(binaryImage);

int i=0;
for (short storedData : storedArray) {
    binaryArray[i] = (short)((storedData >> bitNumber) & 1);
    ++i;
}
```

Currently these are working fine however they are much too slow.  Is there a way to speed this up?  For instance just get the nth bit of every element in a byte[] without iterating over the byte[]?  Ideally I'd like to get this as fast as a lookup in a HashMap (which is what I'm currently using).

PS If there is another way to efficiently store and quickly get/set a set of binary images, I'm all ears.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "as fast as a lookup in a HashMap", please?

Comment: In the course of my application I have to access these images in real time.  A HashMap allows me to do this.  If the conversion from byte[] to vtkImageData is not real time then this will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have smth like this:

```
private static final int MASKS[] = new int[] {
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128};
```

then

```
int imageIndex;
boolean colorSet = (yourByte & MASKS[imageIndex]) != 0;
```

Comment: I'm confused, I have a byte[] that is 512*512*256 (the size of the image), and am not sure how your answer fits in with my question.

Comment: so you iterate over the byte array same way as you do now; can't help with that. My approach saves you the need to shift bits 8 times for every byte though.

Comment: I see.  This seems to be the way to get a bit value, what would be the command to set a bit value?

Comment: targetByte |= MASKS[imageIndex]